# QGIS constraint not null depending on another field value

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, expression, null, constraint

Does anyone know it is possible in QGIS to add a constraint to a field not to be null, only when another field has a certain value.

For example I have a field A that can be with value 'foo' or 'bar' and a field B with free text.
I want the field B to be not null (mandatory to fill), when field A is 'foo'.
But it can be empty when field A is 'bar'.

Hope I'm clear enough in my description.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On field B, for constraints use this expression:

```
case 
    when "field_A" = 'foo' then not (field_B is NULL) 
    when "field_A" <> 'foo' then field_B is NULL or field_B is not NULL 
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! It works like a charm.

Comment: @Babel shouldn't field_B be surrounded by double quotes ("field_B") in your answer?  I thought that fields always needed the double quotes...

Comment: It's not mandatory, fields can also be written without quotes. But probably it's better to use quotes, you're right

Comment: great! is there a way to enforce the not null constraint when field A is 'foo'?

Answer (score 1):

Is imply wanted to point out that this could also be achieved with a if() statement:

```
if("field_A" = 'foo',"field_B" IS NOT NULL,"field_B" IS NULL OR "field_B" IS NOT NULL)
```