# Attribute form constraint, using NULL

Tags: qgis, constraint, mergin-maps

At 3.24.2, I have a Geopackage table containing two fields:

- "interior_observed" is a Boolean, with a Checkbox widget type, true or false.
- "egg_number" is an integer, with a Range widget type.

The widget types will be used with the Mergin Input app, as follows:

- If field staff view the interior of a bird nesting box, they record the number of eggs (greater than or equal to zero) therein.
- If the field staff *do not* view the interior, the number of eggs is unknown, and its resulting value must therefore be NULL.

Unfortunately, every constraint expression that I've tried has no effect on "egg_number".  That is, any value (including NULL) can be applied to "egg_number", regardless of whether "interior_observed" is true or false - as if no constraint exists.  The situation is complicated with additional widget options such as NULL enforcement and default values.

The seemingly most straightforward expression I've tried is 
*nullif("interior_observed" , 'false')*

I've also experimented with variations on the answers at [Attribute form constraint](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427570/attribute-form-constraint?rq=1) and   and [QGIS constraint not null depending on another field value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420382/qgis-constraint-not-null-depending-on-another-field-value)

In summary, how to constrain "egg_number" to NULL when "interior_viewed" = 'false'?

Here's a screenshot of the constraints for "egg_number":

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the "interior_observed" widget settings:

[image]

Comment: Please note: 'false' is a string literal, not a boolean.

Comment: I've edited the OP to included the "interior_observed" widget settings.

Comment: My gut tells me this method will not work. But if it could work you should begin by changing nullif("interior_observed", 'false') to nullif("interior_observed", false). (Remove the quotes around false.)

Comment: Unfortunately, changing *'false'* to *false* made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work the way we imagined. We falsly assumed that the return-value from the expression `nullif("interior_observed", false)` would be assigned to the field content. My guess now is that the return-value is only evaluated as a boolean, merely to decide if the field is valid.

To assign a field value, you need to use the *Default value* of the widget.

It's a bit messy but the following, finally, works for me (that is, in QGIS):

A. In the *egg_number* widget:

1. Add this *Constraint expression*:

> `if("interior_observed"=false and "egg_number" is null, true, false)`
> `OR`
> `if("interior_observed"=true and "egg_number" is not null, true, false)`

2. Tick the *Enforce constraint* checkbox
3. Add this *Default value* expression:

> `if("interior_observed"=false,NULL,NULL)`

```
  *This looks weird, as it always returns NULL, but I think this is needed
  so the value is re-evaluated and re-applied on each update. (Just
  guessing)
```

4. Tick the *Set Apply default value on update* checkbox

B. On the *interior_observed* widget:

1. Untick the *not null* constraint.

Comment: Peter, your solution isn't working for me.  Would you please add a screenshot to your answer? Also, In your second paragraph, what do you mean by "... *Default value* of the widget"?  Finally, I'm using Widget type = Range.  What type are you using?

Comment: @Stu Smith: I have changed my answer. My fields are named different from yours, and
I forgot to adapt them. So I changed "inspected" to "interior_observed", and "eggs" to "egg_number". I assume that will fix it.

Comment: @Stu Smith: The *Default value* is in the last section of the widget properties. See your own screenshots... This value is assigned to the field when you open an insert form for a point.